# Odd requirement of SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns 'Id' and 'Status'.
I want to write a SQL statement to select top 50 rows from this table with 25 rows with Status 1 and 25 rows with Status 2  in one SQL query.

I want my result to have rows with alternate status.

Please suggest me how to write this Query.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: TOP 25 (for Status 1) UNION ALL TOP 25 (for Status 2) will help you

Answer (score 3):

If you use MSSQL you can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 25
    *
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Table1.Status=1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 25
    *
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Table1.Status=2
```

If you use MYSQL you have to use LIMIT. Like this:

```
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        Table1
    WHERE
        Table1.Status=1
    LIMIT 25
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        Table1
    WHERE
        Table1.Status=2
    LIMIT 25
);
```

Comment: nice one i just wrote as like as your one but you give answer before me :(

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server**, use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 25 * FROM TableName WHERE Status=1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 25 * FROM TableName WHERE Status=2
```

For alternative result:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 25 *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Status) as RN FROM TableName WHERE Status=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 25 *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Status) as RN FROM TableName WHERE Status=2
) T
ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: Sorry, but I changed the requirement a bit. I need the rows with alternate status.

Comment: @user2873833: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @user2873833: Edited my answer. Feel free to accept the answer if it is what you are looking for. If you don't know how to accept one, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).